# Does anybody know how to deal with conflict when I create multiple stories in same Wit.ai app?

Tags: facebook, nlp, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I created multiple stories in one app, but when I put these codes in Facebook messenger, it seems that it has conflict. For example, I created a 'question & answer' story and 'greetings' story in my app, but when I send something in Facebook messenger, it always reply me sentence that belongs to 'greetings' conversation. BTW, it worked in Wit.ai bot. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The context is managed by you. Wit only reads it to make prediction of the next step. We never update the context on our side. So you would use actions on your side to update keys in the context. These keys can in turn influence the prediction based on the stories but also to build Bot answers via variable. Wit use the current context (keys only for now), the previous states of the context (at interaction N-1, N-2….) but also the user message (trait entities) to predict the next action.